# SQL Weird Grouping - Matching rows sharing common values for either of two columns?

Tags: sql, sql-server, recursion, mapping, common-table-expression

I am trying to use a recursive CTE to add a Group ID column to my data for mapping purposes. I am using the code here ([SQL Server Weird Grouping Scenario by multiple columns and OR](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51632251/sql-server-weird-grouping-scenario-by-multiple-columns-and-or)), but the output from this code is not working as intended.

I have a SQL Server table `#cache_resale_tbl`, and I would like to add a Group ID column that buckets the rows into groups.

Table Name: `#cache_resale_tbl`

Columns: Key ID, Purchase Order Number ("col1"), Ticket Number ("col2")

I want to add a column which has a group ID, and all rows having the same PO Number OR Ticket Number get the same group ID.

Here is the code I am using:

```
with g (rootid, previd, level, KeyID, col1, col2) as 
(
    select 
        KeyID, 0, 1, KeyID, col1, col2 
    from 
        #cache_resale_tbl

    union all

    select 
        g.rootid, g.KeyID, g.level + 1, v.KeyID, v.col1, v.col2
    from 
        g
    join 
        #cache_resale_tbl v on v.col1 = g.col1 or v.col2 = g.col2
    where 
        v.KeyID > g.KeyID
),
m (KeyID, rootid) as 
(
    select 
        KeyID, min(rootid) 
    from 
        g 
    group by 
        KeyID
)
select 
    v.KeyID, v.col1, v.col2,
    cast(min(rootid) as varchar(50)) as 'Group ID' 
from 
    m
inner join 
    #cache_resale_tbl v on v.KeyID = m.KeyID
group by 
    v.KeyID, v.col1, v.col2;
```

Sample Input for `#cache_resale_tbl`:

```
KeyID   col1   col2
-----------------------
1   PO25303309  255207
2   PO25303304  257459
3   PO25303305  257459
4   PO25303306  257459
5   PO25303307  257459
6   PO25303309  257459
```

Code output:

```
KeyID   col1   col2    Group ID
----------------------------
1   PO25303309  255207  1
2   PO25303304  257459  2
3   PO25303305  257459  2
4   PO25303306  257459  2
5   PO25303307  257459  2
6   PO25303309  257459  1
```

Desired output:

```
KeyID   col1   col2    Group ID
----------------------------
1   PO25303309  255207  1
2   PO25303304  257459  1
3   PO25303305  257459  1
4   PO25303306  257459  1
5   PO25303307  257459  1
6   PO25303309  257459  1
```

My expected output would be that the Group ID column returns all the same number for these rows. The last 5 rows should all have the same Group ID because they have the same col2 value. And the first ticket also belongs to this group because row 1 and 6 have the same col1 value. Any row that has the same col1 or col2 value should be in the same group ID. Therefore, my desired output is to map these all into one group, which the code I'm using doesn't seem to do.

Any help on this would be greatly appreciated :) Thanks!

Comment: When groupId will get 2? Any examples for that?

Comment: If the input data table had an additional KeyID =7, with col1 = PO25303310 and col2 = 331502, then that would get GroupID = 2. The reason for that is this new row I'm adding here does not have any col1 or col2 values in common with the first six rows.

Comment: Why row 1 and 2 has to get same group id? eventhough both are different?

Comment: Row 2 is related to row 6 because they have the same col2. Row 6 is related to row 1 because they have the same col1. Therefore,  rows 1 and 2 need the same group ID for my mapping.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe this does what is originally asked in the question with one caveat. Orders not repeated in either col1 or col2 are grouped together (uncomment line `union all select 8,   'PO25303311',  331503` in the CTE for an example).

```
;with cache_resale_tbl as(
select
 1 KeyID,  'PO25303309' col1, 255207 col2
union all select 2,   'PO25303304',  257459
union all select 3,   'PO25303305',  257459
union all select 4,   'PO25303306',  257459
union all select 5,   'PO25303307',  257459
union all select 6,   'PO25303309',  257459
union all select 7,   'PO25303310',  331502
--union all select 8,   'PO25303311',  331503
)


,CountRepeatVal AS(
select 
    cache_resale_tbl.*
    ,CntCol1                = COUNT(*) over (partition by col1)
    ,CntCol2                = COUNT(*) over (partition by col2)

from cache_resale_tbl

)

,Grouped AS(
select 
    CountRepeatVal.*
    ,Groups                 = case when (CountRepeatVal.CntCol1 > 1 OR CountRepeatVal.CntCol2 > 1) then 0 else 1 end

from CountRepeatVal
)

select 
    --Grouped.*
    Grouped.KeyID
    ,Grouped.col1
    ,Grouped.col2
    ,GROUP_ID       = DENSE_RANK() OVER(ORDER BY Groups)

FROM Grouped
```

Here's the [db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2017&fiddle=08c81fb2c0ea23c8d8f2ec47c059fb3c)