# How to consolidate two id columns, identifying which rows belong to same set of related IDs

Tags: sql, google-bigquery

I have 2 ID columns that are created/collected independently.  I'm trying to consolidate these two ID columns into one by determining which rows are part of the same related group of ids based on either of the two ID columns.  I would consider the rows to be related based on a few rules:

1: If a LOAN has the same value in multiple rows, they belong to the same group (in the example for reference only.)  I've called it loan_group. No issues here.

2: If a COLLATERAL has the same value in multiple rows, they belong to the temporary group.  I've called it collateral_group (same rule as #1.)  No issues here.

3: Finally, and I'm not sure how to phrase this exactly, but any time there is overlap between values that are part of the same group (across loan and collateral columns), those groups should be further consolidated.  For example:

```
LOAN  COLLATERAL  loan_group  collateral_group  final_grouping
----  ----------- ----------  ----------------  --------------
L1    C1*         1           1                 **1**
L2**  C1*         2           1                 **1**
L5    C8          3           2                 2
L2**  C4***       2           3                 **1**
L6    C8          4           2                 2
L7    C9          5           4                 3
L8    C4***       6           3                 **1**
```

*because rows 1 and 2 both have the value C1, they would be assigned to the same final grouping

**because row 2 has the LOAN value L2, this means we can include row 4 in the consolidated final grouping.  That row can be linked back to row 1 via the L2/C1 link

***finally, because row 4 includes the COLLATERAL value C4, this means we can include row 7 in the consolidated final grouping.  That row can be linked back to row one via the L2/C4 & L2/C1 links

The data set is roughly 15m unique combinations of LOAN + COLLATERAL. The groups will likely crossover a few thousand (maybe +10 thousand) IDs in some edge cases.  I've run into some resource issues on BQ testing some solutions (but those issues are mostly a do with my inexperience with BQ.)  Just a heads up if that impacts anybody's recommendation.

Really appreciate your time, apologies for being overly vague/brief in my first version...

Comment: This looks like a graph-walking problem.  BigQuery doesn't have native support for recursive CTEs or hierarchical queries, so I don't think this can be done with a single query.

Comment: the question is crystal clear to me! will answer if reopened. @ehitch - edit your question with little more details so it will qualify for re-openning

Comment: @ehitch - looks like this post will not be reopened - you might want to post new question so I will be able to answer

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Below is for BigQuery Standard SQL

As Gordon mentioned in comments - BigQuery doesn't have native support for recursive CTEs or hierarchical queries, so this cannot be done with just a single query!

BUT ..., this can be implemented using recently introduced [scripting](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/reference/standard-sql/scripting) as in example below

```
DECLARE rows_count, run_away_stop INT64 DEFAULT 0;

CREATE TEMP TABLE input AS (
  SELECT 'L1' loan, 'C1' collateral UNION ALL
  SELECT 'L2', 'C1' UNION ALL
  SELECT 'L5', 'C8' UNION ALL
  SELECT 'L2', 'C4' UNION ALL
  SELECT 'L6', 'C8' UNION ALL
  SELECT 'L7', 'C9' UNION ALL
  SELECT 'L8', 'C4'
);

CREATE TEMP TABLE initial_grouping AS 
SELECT ARRAY_AGG(collateral ORDER BY collateral) arr 
FROM input
GROUP BY loan;

LOOP
  SET rows_count = (SELECT COUNT(1) FROM initial_grouping);
  SET run_away_stop = run_away_stop + 1;

  CREATE OR REPLACE TEMP TABLE initial_grouping AS
  SELECT ANY_VALUE(arr) arr FROM (
    SELECT ARRAY(SELECT DISTINCT val FROM UNNEST(arr) val ORDER BY val) arr
    FROM (
      SELECT ANY_VALUE(arr1) arr1, ARRAY_CONCAT_AGG(arr) arr    
      FROM (
        SELECT t1.arr arr1, t2.arr arr2, ARRAY(SELECT DISTINCT val FROM UNNEST(ARRAY_CONCAT( t1.arr, t2.arr)) val ORDER BY val) arr 
        FROM initial_grouping t1, initial_grouping t2 
        WHERE (SELECT COUNT(1) FROM UNNEST(t1.arr) val JOIN UNNEST(t2.arr) val USING(val)) > 0
      ) GROUP BY FORMAT('%t', arr1)
    )
  ) GROUP BY FORMAT('%t', arr);

  IF (rows_count = (SELECT COUNT(1) FROM initial_grouping) AND run_away_stop > 1) OR run_away_stop > 10 THEN BREAK; END IF;
END LOOP;

SELECT loan, collateral, final_grouping FROM input 
JOIN (SELECT ROW_NUMBER() OVER() final_grouping, arr FROM initial_grouping) 
ON collateral IN UNNEST(arr) 
ORDER BY loan, collateral;
```

Above script produces below result (which I believe is exactly what you are looking for)

```
Row loan    collateral  final_grouping   
1   L1      C1          1    
2   L2      C1          1    
3   L2      C4          1    
4   L5      C8          3    
5   L6      C8          3    
6   L7      C9          2    
7   L8      C4          1
```

Please note: when applying to real data - make sure you set appropriate max for run_away_stop (in above script it is 10 - see last statement within LOOP - you might need to increase it to make sure conversion will complete)

Finally: to apply to your real table:

1 - remove `CREATE TEMP TABLE input (...)` statement
 2 - replace `input` with `your_project.your_dataset.your_table` in `CREATE TEMP TABLE initial_grouping AS ...` statement

Comment: glad it worked for you. Consider also voting up if not yet :o)

Answer (score 1):

Your description is a bit vague, so hard to tell whether this is the asked for solution. Try to elaborate a bit more on exactly what you need regarding "belong to same 'path' of groups and then to perform allocation within group."

```
SELECT Loan, Collateral, COUNT(*) AS Group FROM [TABLE]
GROUP BY Loan, Collateral
```

You need to change the tableName [TABLE]

-- UPDATE

There might be a problem with your presentation, as the numbers don't add up.

I've tried to make a double grouping here, but there seems to be a problem around L2 and C8 which breaks the logic, as these two values behave differently.

```
SELECT * FROM [Tabel]  AS A
LEFT JOIN
(
SELECT [Loan], COUNT(*) AS Rows_Loan FROM [Tabel]
GROUP BY [Loan]
) AS T
ON A.Loan = T.Loan

LEFT JOIN (
SELECT [Collateral], COUNT(*) AS Rows_Collateral FROM [Tabel]
GROUP BY [Collateral]
) AS T2
ON A.Collateral = T2.Collateral
```

Result:

```
Loan    Collateral  Loan    Rows_Loan   Collateral  Rows_Collateral
L1      C1          L1      1           C1          2
L2      C1          L2      2           C1          2
L5      C8          L5      1           C8          2
L2      C4          L2      2           C4          1
L6      C8          L6      1           C8          2
```

Comment: Thank you Mikhail and Gordon, I've added some detail.  I hope it qualifies for reopening.

Comment: Thanks again Gordon for reference to "grap-walking", that helped refined some of my searches a bit.  This link appears to be an answer to my question, but I can't quite work it out in BQ... https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51632251/sql-server-weird-grouping-scenario-by-multiple-columns-and-or

Comment: Thank you very much, Mikhail Berlyant!  I am reviewing over the next couple days.  TBH, the logic behind the query is taking some time to validate.  The output you have is correct, so I'll mark as correct in the next couple days, but want to validate first (unfortunately some of your methods are a bit outside of my wheelhouse.)  Thank you very much.

Comment: Thank you very much to Mikhail.  This did the trick.  Exactly what I was looking for as far as I can tell.  I did run into resource issues with BQ for long "paths" (3k+) but that could be my issue rather than BQs...

I may open a similar question for R, as I've been trying to solve the problem there as well.

Again, works exactly as I needed it to... exactly.