# Linking Related IDs together through two other ID columns

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a table of about 100k rows with the following layout:

```
+----+-----------+------------+-------------------+
| ID |    PIN    |    RAID    | Desired Output ID |
+----+-----------+------------+-------------------+
|  1 | 80602627  | 1737852-1  |                 1 |
|  2 | 80602627  | 34046655-1 |                 1 |
|  3 | 351418172 | 33661      |                 2 |
|  4 | 351418172 | 33661      |                 2 |
|  5 | 351418172 | 33661      |                 2 |
|  6 | 351418172 | 34443321-1 |                 2 |
|  7 | 491863017 | 26136      |                 3 |
|  8 | 491863017 | 34575      |                 3 |
|  9 | 491863017 | 34575      |                 3 |
| 10 | 661254727 | 26136      |                 3 |
| 11 | 661254727 | 26136      |                 3 |
| 12 | NULL      | 7517       |                 4 |
| 13 | NULL      | 7517       |                 4 |
| 14 | NULL      | 7517       |                 4 |
| 15 | NULL      | 7517       |                 4 |
| 16 | NULL      | 7517       |                 4 |
| 17 | 554843813 | 33661      |                 2 |
| 18 | 554843813 | 33661      |                 2 |
+----+-----------+------------+-------------------+
```

The ID column has unique values, with the PIN and RAID columns being two separate identifying numbers used to group linked IDs together. The Desired Output ID column is what I would like SQL to do, essentially looking at both the PIN and RAID columns to spot where there are any relationships between them.

So for example Where Desired Output ID = 2, IDs 3-6 match on PIN = 351418172, and then IDs 17-18 also match as the RAID of 33661 was in the rows for IDs 3-5.

To add as well, NULLs will be in the PIN Column but not in any others.

I did spot a similar question [Text](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59006131/how-to-consolidate-two-id-columns-identifying-which-rows-belong-to-same-set-of) however as it is in BigQuery I wasnt sure it would help.

Have been trying to crack this one for a while with no luck, any help massively appreciated.

Comment: Please explain in full why those combinations of `PIN` and `RAID` should map to those `Desired Output ID`s. It is not very clear, and the single example doesn't help too much. Do you basically want that if a subsequent row contains either field with the same value as a previous row, it should get the same `Output ID`?

Comment: The IDs are user accounts and we have multiple accounts for the same person. The PIN is an external ID from Experian that states which accounts are the same person, and RAID is an internal calculation to spot linked accounts where name/address and DOB match. Where we have incorrect data input or Experian are missing an ID is the overlap where I need the above to calculate a new ID by looking at both columns. I do not believe you can use subsequent rows as the rows aren't ordered in any particular way across both RAID and PIN, and the ID columns has had its figures replaced for this post.

Comment: Well, "subsequent rows" here was just for illustration. Thanks for elucidating! :-)

Answer (score 0):

I suppose DENSE_RANK can solve your problem.  Not sure what the combination of PIN and RAID should be, but I think you'll be able to figure it out how to do it like this:

```
SELECT *,DENSE_RANK( )  over (ORDER BY isnull(pin,id) ),DENSE_RANK( )  over (ORDER BY raid)
FROM accounts
```

Answer (score 0):

I believe I have found a bit of a bodged solution to this. It runs very slowly as it goes row by row and will only go two links deep on PIN/RAID, but this should be sufficient for 99%+ cases.

Would appreciate any suggestions to speeding it up if anything is immediately obvious.

ID in post above is DebtorNo in Code:

```
DECLARE     @Counter INT = 1
DECLARE     @EndCounter INT = 0

IF OBJECT_ID('Tempdb..#OrigACs') IS NOT NULL 
BEGIN 
DROP TABLE  #OrigACs
END 

SELECT      DebtorNo,
            Name,
            PostCode,
            DOB,
            RAJoin,
            COALESCE(PIN,DebtorNo COLLATE DATABASE_DEFAULT) AS PIN,
            RelatedAssets,
            RAID,
            PINRelatedAssets

INTO        #OrigACs

FROM        MIReporting..HC_RA_Test_Data RA

IF OBJECT_ID('Tempdb..#Accounts') IS NOT NULL 
BEGIN 
DROP TABLE  #Accounts
END 

SELECT      *,
            ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY CAST(RA.DebtorNo AS INT)) AS Row

INTO        #Accounts

FROM        #OrigACs RA

ORDER BY    CAST(RA.DebtorNo AS INT)

CREATE INDEX Temp_HC_Index ON #OrigACs (RAID,PIN)

SET         @EndCounter = (SELECT MAX(Row) FROM #Accounts)

WHILE       @Counter <= @EndCounter 

BEGIN

IF OBJECT_ID('Tempdb..#RAID1') IS NOT NULL 
BEGIN 
DROP TABLE  #RAID1
END 

SELECT      *

INTO        #RAID1

FROM        #OrigACs A

WHERE       A.RAID IN (SELECT RAID FROM #Accounts WHERE [Row] = @Counter)

IF OBJECT_ID('Tempdb..#PIN1') IS NOT NULL 
BEGIN 
DROP TABLE  #PIN1
END 

SELECT      *

INTO        #PIN1

FROM        #OrigACs A

WHERE       A.PIN IN (SELECT PIN FROM #RAID1)

IF OBJECT_ID('Tempdb..#RAID2') IS NOT NULL 
BEGIN 
DROP TABLE  #RAID2
END 

SELECT      *

INTO        #RAID2

FROM        #OrigACs A

WHERE       A.RAID IN (SELECT RAID FROM #PIN1)

IF OBJECT_ID('Tempdb..#PIN2') IS NOT NULL 
BEGIN 
DROP TABLE  #PIN2
END 

SELECT      *

INTO        #PIN2

FROM        #OrigACs A

WHERE       A.PIN IN (SELECT PIN FROM #RAID2)

INSERT INTO MIReporting..HC_RA_Final_ACs

SELECT      DebtorNo,
            Name,
            PostCode,
            DOB,
            RAJoin,
            CASE
                WHEN PIN = DebtorNo COLLATE DATABASE_DEFAULT THEN NULL
                ELSE PIN
            END AS PIN,
            RelatedAssets,
            RAID,
            PINRelatedAssets,
            COALESCE((SELECT MAX(FRAID) FROM MIReporting..HC_RA_Final_ACs),0) + 1 AS FRAID

FROM        #PIN2

SET         @Counter = (SELECT MIN([ROW]) FROM #Accounts O WHERE O.DebtorNo NOT IN (SELECT DebtorNo FROM MIReporting..HC_RA_Final_ACs));

END;

SELECT      *

FROM        MIReporting..HC_RA_Final_ACs

DROP TABLE  #OrigACs
DROP TABLE  #Accounts
DROP TABLE  #RAID1
DROP TABLE  #PIN1
DROP TABLE  #RAID2
DROP TABLE  #PIN2
```